# How to search multiple line and replace these multiples lines into place?

Tags: regex

Currently I have text based files, some part of these files is like:

```
\#:some comment
msgid ""
"CCCCC"
msgstr ""

\#: some comment
msgid ""
"CCCCC"
"DDDDD"
msgstr ""

\#:some comment
msgid ""
"CCCCC"
"DDDDD"
"EEEEE"
msgstr ""
```

And I have a regex `msgid ""(([^\n#])*(\n+))+msgstr ""` to match all these lines except for comment.

My final goal is to find any strings in or after msgid and replace them to msgstr

Like:

```
\#:some comment
msgid ""
"CCCCC"
msgstr ""
"CCCCC"

\#: some comment
msgid ""
"CCCCC"
"DDDDD"
msgstr ""
"CCCCC"
"DDDDD"

\#:some comment
msgid ""
"CCCCC"
"DDDDD"
"EEEEE"
msgstr ""
"CCCCC"
"DDDDD"
"EEEEE"
```

So when use search and replace in regular expression, $1 only match the last line of each group. I was hoping $1 can match the strings in between msgid and msgstr, so that it can be replaced after msgstr.

Any suggestion will be greatly helpful!

Comment: try appending all the lines into a single String ( in case of java ) and match the regex to pull out all the matches in that string.

Comment: What flavor regex are you using? What do you use them in (perl, sed, awk, javascript)? Would you like to add some corresponding tags?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an sed demonstrator `sed -En ":a;N;$!ba;s/msgid \"\"((([^\n#])*(\n+))+)msgstr \"\"/--\1--/g;l"`. 
Without knowing more of your environment I chose this for testing.
You do not need sed, this is just to show what and how I tested.

- it has to escape the `"`
- the **trick** is to add **another capture group** which includes the current `(...)+`,
  which is because of position still `\1`
- the demonstrator encloses the matched string in "--", to show what was matched, it is what I understand you want
- the comment are still there because they are NOT matched
- msgid and msgstr are NOT in the output because they ARE matched, like your regex also did

For the given sample input it gives the output:

```
\#:some comment
--
"CCCCC"
--

\#: some comment
--
"CCCCC"
"DDDDD"
--

\#:some comment
--
"CCCCC"
"DDDDD"
"EEEEE"
--
```

The regex in your flavor would be (I guess)
    `msgid ""((([^\n#])*(\n+))+)msgstr ""`

Let me know which language/tool/flavor you use and show me your code (not just the regex) and I will adapt the answer to more closely fit your needs.
You said you want to match the text between msgid and msgstr. I read that to include the `""` with the msg* NOT with the matched text. That does not match the desired output.
If desired output is more important than the description I can also change towards that, but I need your code in addition to your regex.